# Stream Exception opening a file on an iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, iostream, dicom

I am trying to display a dicom image on an iPad using Imebra.
I was able to display the dicom image successfully on an iPhone4 and an iPad simulator. But I had trouble with an actual iPad.
I am getting the below error while displaying the image.

```
    [stream::openFile (unicode)]
    file: /Users/Workspace/Img_Proc/DDemo/Imebra/base/src/stream.cpp  line: 180
    exception type: N8puntoexe19streamExceptionOpenE
    exception message: stream::openFile failure


    [stream::openFile (unicode)]
    file: /Users/Workspace/Img_Proc/DDemo/Imebra/base/src/stream.cpp  line: 183
    exception type: N8puntoexe19streamExceptionOpenE
    exception message: stream::openFile failure


    [stream::openFile (ansi)]
    file: /Users/Workspace/Img_Proc/DDemo/Imebra/base/src/stream.cpp  line: 104
    exception type: N8puntoexe19streamExceptionOpenE
    exception message: stream::openFile failure
```

Here are some more details:
Framework Added: libiconv.2.4.0.dylib
iPad Device iOS: 4.3.1(8G4)

How might I resolve this?

Comment: I have downloaded the Imebra SDK , it only contains C and C++ files , do you have any referance link through which i can know how can i read data set or tags of DICOM file and display image on iPhone ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you been given GDCM a try ? See:

http://gdcm.sf.net